# Why am I unable to send JSON data to the ipcRenderer

Tags: javascript, json, electron, dom-events, ipcrenderer

In my `main.js app.on("ready")`, I call a function called `runTimer()` which contains the following:

```
const runTimer = function(){
    const { net } = require('electron')
    setInterval(async function () {
        if (seconds == 0) {
            const request = await net.request("https://localhost:6001/api/traintimes");
            request.on("response", (response) => {
                if (response.statusCode === 200) {
                    response.on("data", (data) => {
                        mainWindow.webContents.send("render-update", data);
                        console.log(`Body: ${data}`);
                    });
                    response.on("end", () => {
                        console.log("No more data in response.");
                    });
                }
            });
            request.end()
            seconds = 5;
        }
        seconds--
        mainWindow.webContents.send("counting", seconds);

    },1000)
}
```

I am able to see the data in the console that I wish to send to the UI when I console log it in the following line:

```
console.log(`Body: data`);
```

so I expect the following line to send the same JSON data to the UI.

```
mainWindow.webContents.send("render-update", data);
```

However, I get a unit8Array result in the UI, and I am not sure why it just doesn't display the JSON result which is logged in the console in the line right after it.

**IPC Renderer**

```
ipcRenderer.on("fetched-train-update", (evt, data) => {
  console.log(data);
})
```

Basically, instead of getting JSON data logged in the UI console, I get unit8Array as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Where did the screenshot come from? Is it from Chrome dev tools network panel? If so, which tab, preview or response?

Comment: @RandyCasburn it's from the console tab in the chrome dev tools

Comment: I had to change the webcontent.send to this mainWindow.webContents.send("render-update", `Body: ${data}`); and i am not sure why this works